# LIBGDX Collision detection using 2 Arrays and 2 Iterators only detecting collisions for first object

Tags: arrays, iterator, libgdx, collision

I have searched high and low across the internet for several hours but couldn't find an example of this precise problem. If you are reading this fear not, the answer is below.

If you are using 2 libgdx Arrays and Iterators to check collisions between the bounding rectangles of two object types, you may encounter the following problem:

The second iterator only detects collisions for the first object in the first array. An example of this would be:

- You have an array of enemy objects and an array of bullet objects.
- The bullets are flying through all enemies except the first one spawned.
- However the bullets are being deleted when they go out of bounds.
- Once the first enemy has been hit, you can then only hit the next one that was spawned.
- Your code looks like this:

  ```
  Iterator<Enemy> iterEn = arrayEnemies.getIterator();
  Iterator<Bullet> iterBul = arrayBullets.getIterator();
  while (iterEn.hasNext){
  Enemy e = iterEn.next();
  while (iterBul.hasNext(){
      Bullet b = iterBul.next();
      if (b.isOutOfBounds)iterBul.remove();
      if (b.getRectangle().overlaps(e.getRectangle()){ 
          iterBul.remove();
          iterEn.remove();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare two iterators and expect to use one within the other, the following happens:

1. Both iterators are intialized with their hasNext() boolean as true.
2. The enemy iterator starts the first iteration with the first Enemy
   object in the Enemies array.
3. The Enemy iterator calls upon the second iterator, which then
   iterates through all the bullets to check for collisions with the
   Enemy object.
4. The Bullet iterator hasNext() is set to false once this is done.
5. The next iteration of Enemy iterator then calls for Bullet iterator
   to check collisions, but the hasNext() is still false, so it skips
   checking any Bullets in the Bullets array.

**Solution**: Initialize the bullets iterator within the iteration loop of the Enemy iterator

```
Iterator<Enemy> iterEn = arrayEnemies.getIterator();

while (iterEn.hasNext){
   Enemy e = iterEn.next();

    //initialise the bullet iterator each time here
    Iterator<Bullet> iterBul = arrayBullets.getIterator();

    while (iterBul.hasNext(){
        Bullet b = iterBul.next();
        if (b.isOutOfBounds)iterBul.remove();
        if (b.getRectangle().overlaps(e.getRectangle()){ 
            iterBul.remove();
            iterEn.remove();
        }
    }
}
```